# Hibernate Spatial - 'Invalid endian flag value encountered' Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I'm trying to run a simple query in Hibernate Spatial 4.0 on PostgreSQL 9.3.  I have a number of objects in a table with latitude/longitude values, and I'm trying to query objects that fall within a given radius of a particular latitude/longitude.  The geometry values seem to be persisted without any problem, and are defined like this in my entity class:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "Geometry", nullable = true)
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private Point coordinates = null;
```

I don't have any errors when persisting objects with the `coordinates` value set.  However, when I run a query, I see the following Exception:

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

    <snip />

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
    org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2031)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1832)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:264)
```

The query I'm running looks like this:

```
Query query = this.entityManager
        .createQuery(
                "SELECT v FROM MyEntity v WHERE within(v.coordinates, :filter) = true",
                MyEntity.class);
query.setParameter("filter", point);
```

I came across [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215212/postgis-geometry-saving-invalid-endian-flag-value-encountered) that mentions the same error, but I'm declaring my `coordinates` property the same way that is mentioned in the answer and still get this error.

For the record, I've tried using PostGIS 1.5.2 and PostGIS 2.1.0.  I've also tried different version of my PostgreSQL JDBC driver, from 8.4 to 9.3.  Regardless of the library version I still encounter this issue.

Can anyone shed any light on what could be happening here?  Is my query wrong?  Is my property not defined correctly?  Is there something else I should be trying?  I'm completely stuck and at a loss for what could be the issue here.  Any advice would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: The `within` function was renamed `ST_Within` several releases ago. Furthermore, evaluating `= true` is redundant, since the function returns a Boolean. Also, have you seen [this answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215212/postgis-geometry-saving-invalid-endian-flag-value-encountered)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="Geometry")
@Type(type = "org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType")
private Point point;
```

Comment: As far as using HQL queries to retrieve the data... good luck, never got that portion working, ended up using native queries through JPA.

Comment: You'll notice that's nearly the EXACT annotation I have on my entity, as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Look a little closer.  Yours: org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType
Mine: org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType

Comment: With yours, I get an error on deployment:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType

I do not see this class in the hibernate-spatial-4.0.jar library.  I believe my annotation was correct.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by adding the below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
    <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.1</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of my old dependency: com.vividsolutions